# How to use importlib.metadata from Python 3.8

Tags: python-importlib, python-3.8

I've been trying to understand the importlib.metadata library from Python 3.8 but can't seem to figure why it won't work.
As per the documentation https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/importlib.metadata.html, after installing Python3.8 and wheel package (via pip):

```py
>> from importlib.metadata import version  
>> version('wheel')
```

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'MetadataPathFinder' from 'importlib.metadata'
```

Answer (score 0):

Running the following command helped in my case `python -c "import importlib.metadata, shutil, pathlib; file = pathlib.Path(importlib.metadata.__file__); str(file).endswith('__init__.py') and shutil.rmtree(file.parent) and print('removed', file.parent)"`

Taken from https://bugs.python.org/issue38342#msg353736